# Insertion Sort not working for single digit entries if #entries> 9

Tags: python

I am trying to implement insertion sort using python. Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
N=int(input())
A=input().split()

#A=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
B_sorted=A.copy()
C= A.copy()
def inssort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        key = arr[i]
        j = i-1
        while (j >=0 and key < arr[j]):
            arr[j+1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1
        arr[j+1] = key 
        
inssort(B_sorted)
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for j in range(0,len(A)):
        if A[i]==B_sorted[j]:
            C[i]=j+1
            break
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
for x in B_sorted:
    print (x, "",end="")
```

My code works for the following set of entries:

- [9,8,7,...,2,1]
- [20,19,...,12,11]
- [20,19,...,11,10]

but it doesn't work for following
[10,9,8,...,2,1]

I don't understand what exactly is the issue here.

I tried to go to the detail by printing the output at every loop:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
['10', '8', '9', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
['10', '7', '8', '9', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
['10', '6', '7', '8', '9', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
['10', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '4', '3', '2', '1']
['10', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '3', '2', '1']
['10', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '2', '1']
['10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1']
['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Looks like for some reason at the first iteration j is not taking the value 0 for this particular sequence. As I mentioned before, it works perfectly for a lot of other sequences.

Kindly help.

Comment: You're sorting strings, not numbers. In a lexicographical ordering, `'10'` is smaller than `'2'`. If you want normal numeric ordering, you'd need to sort parsed numbers, or implement your own custom comparison function.

Comment: To test that that's the case, replace your `A` with `A = list(range(10, -1, -1))`, then try sorting that. It should be ordered as expected since the list now contains numbers.

Comment: Ohh damn! That was a really intelligent catch! Thank you very much.